# how to change access time of a file using utime and mktime syscalls and c++?

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

I was trying to change the access time of a file, but i didn't get the result i wanted.

this is what i tried:

```cpp
struct tm time;
    time.tm_sec=56;
    time.tm_min=48;
    time.tm_hour=20;
    time.tm_mday=12;
    time.tm_mon=8;
    time.tm_year=1905;
struct utimbuf utime_par;
utime_par.actime=mktime(&time);
if(utime("file_name",&utime_par)!=0)
    {
    
      perror("smash error: utime failed");
      std::cout<<"entered";
      return;
    }
```

when I run on linux terminal

```
ls -l file_name
```

I get

```
-rwxrw-rw- 1 student student 3133 Jun 20  4461763 README.txt
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you check the result of `utime`?

Comment: You should start from your tm struct values. tm_year should contain `years since 1900`. Refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm

Comment: @StephenNewell yes I did

Comment: Where? There's no error checking in your code.

Comment: @StephenNewell I did in my source file , i didn't write it here but I will edit it in now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html) of the function `utime`, `struct utimbuf` (which you pass to the function `utime`) is defined in the following way:

```
struct utimbuf {
    time_t actime;       /* access time */
    time_t modtime;      /* modification time */
};
```

However, you are only setting the `actime` field of this `struct`, which means that the field `modtime` has an indeterminate value when you pass it to the function `utime`.

In your case, you probably want to set both fields to the same time value:

```
utime_par.actime  = mktime( &time );
utime_par.modtime = mktime( &time );
```

Or, if you don't want to call the function `mktime` twice (which is a bit inefficient), you can also write:

```
utime_par.actime  = mktime( &time );
utime_par.modtime = time_par.actime;
```

Also, as already pointed out in the comments section, the field `tm_year` in a [`struct tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) should not be the absolute year, but rather the number of years since the year `1900`. Therefore, it is probably wrong that you write `1905` into this field, as that corresponds to the year `3805`.

Another issue is that you should set the field `tm_isdst` in the `struct tm`, to indicate whether daylight savings was in effect. You can simply set this field to a negative value, which will tell `mktime` that you are not providing this information, and that it should therefore determine this itself. By not setting this field, the value of this field will be indeterminate, which means that you may be providing `mktime` false information about whether daylight savings was in effect. This could lead to the timestamp on the file being wrong by one hour.

Comment: thank you it worked , I had to alse give the month I want as `month -1` and as you said `year-1900`  maybe the other parameters need changing too?

Comment: @Raea6789: According to the documentation of [`mktime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html), the fields `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` are ignored. So there is no need to set them. However, as pointed out in my answer, the field `tm_isdst` is not ignored, so it should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have successfully updated the access time of your `file_name`, but you failed to check the result with `ls`.

I just copy your code, and change the access time of my file successfully.

The **problem** is:

```sh
ls -l file_name
```

`ls` shows the `mtime` — updated when the file contents change. This is the "default" file time in most cases. **But I guess you have not changed the file contents of your file**

What you should do is:

```sh
ls -l --time=atime your-file-name
```

What does `--time` mean? You could check its meaning by `man ls`

```
       --time=WORD
              change the default of using modification times; access time (-u): atime, access, use; change time (-c): ctime, status; birth time: birth, creation;

              with -l, WORD determines which time to show; with --sort=time, sort by WORD (newest first)
```